# Can mail sent by SMTP be intercepted?

Tags: email, smtp

In my project, I use SMTP to send mail. When customers register, they will send their username and password to their email to confirm their registration with their personal information. But it seems that during the mailing process, the information was leaked and another service party was able to contact them before us

Comment: Yes, it can be intercepted under certain conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Any network node between your user and yourself can view emails sent via SMTP.

That‘s why sensitive data should not be sent via unencrypted email.

As a suggestion, have your users enter their credentials in a form on an SSL protected web page.